# "BadValueError: name must be under 500 bytes." when i download a big file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download, blobstore

I have a problem when i try download a file since blobstore. My aplication do a merge of some files with data in the blobstore to create a big file (50 MB). This is my code:

```
    fileName=""
    def post(self):
    cadenaSalida = []
    for empiece in range(1):
        cadenaSubsidio="ficheroCSV" + str(empiece)
        logging.info(cadenaSubsidio)
        gqlQuery = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename=:1",cadenaSubsidio)
        blobs  = gqlQuery.fetch(1)
        if blobs :
            for doc in blobs :
                logging.info(doc.key())
                blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(doc.key())
                cadenaSalida.append(blob_reader.readlines(None))
                logging.info("DESPUES DE LEER TODO EL FICHERO")
        else:
            logging.info("NO HAY DOCUMENTOS")


    logging.info("Creamos el fichero")
    cadenaTotal="csvTotal.csv"
    logging.info(cadenaTotal)
    self.creartxt(cadenaTotal)
    logging.info(self.fileName)
    f=self.abrirtxt()
    logging.info(f)
    self.escribirtxt(f, cadenaSalida)
    self.cerrartxt(f)

    resource = str(urllib.unquote(self.fileName))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

The value of self.fileName it's assigned:

```
    def creartxt (self,nombreCSV):
    # Create the file
    self.fileName = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename=nombreCSV)

   def abrirtxt (self):
    f= files.open(self.fileName, 'a')
    return f
```

Other's method that I use are:

```
    def escribirtxt(self,f, lineas):
    logging.info("VAMOS A ESCRIBIR EL TXT")
    for linea in lineas:
        logging.info(linea)
        try:
            f.write(str(linea))
        except:
            logging.info("Da el punetero errror e intentamos abrir el fichero")
            f= files.open(self.fileName, 'a')
            logging.info("Antes de escribir")
            f.write(linea)
            logging.info("Despues de escribir")



   def cerrartxt(self,f):
       f.close()  
       files.finalize(self.fileName)
```

But, it appear the error: "BadValueError: name must be under 500 bytes.". How can i avoid this error?

The stacktrace is:

Sorry, the stacktrace is:

```
name must be under 500 bytes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ono-hat-vv2/1.369495673401411273/com/__init__.py", line 207, in post
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 300, in get
    blob_keys = cls.__normalize_and_convert_keys(blob_keys)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/blobstore/blobstore.py", line 390, in __normalize_and_convert_keys
    keys[index] = datastore.Key.from_path(cls.kind(), str(key), namespace='')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 514, in from_path
    ValidateString(id_or_name, 'name')
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 176, in ValidateString
    raise exception('%s must be under %d bytes.' % (name, max_len))
BadValueError: name must be under 500 bytes.
```

The error occurs in the line:

blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)

Regards.

Comment: You need to include the stack trace, which line of code is the error being raised on ?

Comment: You are not showing how/what self.filename is being set to.  In the docs the value passed to  blobstore.BlobInfo.get() should be a  blob key.

Comment: ok, I've added all my methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```
gqlQuery = blobstore.BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename=:1",self.cadenaTotal)
blobs  = gqlQuery.fetch(1)
    if blobs :
        for doc in blobs:
            logging.info(doc.key())
            blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(doc.key())
```

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So have a look at `self.fileName = files.blobstore.create(mime_ ....` it  doesn't create a filename but a writable handler.

Which you proceed to open and write to.

But then you are do the following

```
resource = str(urllib.unquote(self.fileName))
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
```

But BlobInfo.get() takes a blobkey not a blobfile object or whatever `str(urllib.unquote(self.fileName))` is returning.  Hence the validation error.

You should probably be using `get_blob_key(create_file_name)` Gets the blob key for a finalized blobstore file.  but not 100% sure about that.